# How to add classes or styles dynamically in odoo 16.0 qweb template

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-16

I have many boolean fields and i am trying to add classes dynamically in odoo template.
[Odoo docs qweb templates](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/es/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#attributes)

I try

```xml
<t t-foreach="planes" t-as="plan">
    <p t-attf-class="{{plan.blog ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}}">Blog</p>
    <p t-attf-class="{plan.blog ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}">Blog</p>
    <p t-attf-class="plan.blog ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'">Blog</p>
    <p t-attf-class="plan.blog ? text-success : text-danger">Blog</p>
</t>
```

Expected render:

```html
<p class="text-success">Blog</p>
<p class="text-danger">Blog</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the following syntaxes:

```py
t-attf-class="{{ 'text-success' if plan.blog else 'text-danger' }}"
```

Used in mrp [work order](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/mrp/report/mrp_production_templates.xml#L112C21-L112C87) report template

```js
t-attf-class="#{record.blog.raw_value ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}"
```

Used in [workcenter](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/mrp/views/mrp_workcenter_views.xml#L165C34-L165C111) Kanban view

Or

```js
t-attf-class="{{plan.blog ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}}"
```

Used in website client action template ([configurator](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/website/static/src/client_actions/configurator/configurator.xml))